# Open Storyboard-view manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uialertview

I have an application using Storyboard. On a view there is an AlertViewDialog.

When the user clicks the first button ("Yes"), how can I open an other view on the Storyboard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

my be this can help :

1. Drag a View in Then go to Identity Inspector (Shortcut: option+apple+3).
2. Select the newly dragged View and give unique name from identify inspector in title Storyboard ID . 
   // see the image for reference
   [image]

create SecondViewController class (.h &.m) subclass of viewController .

then from alert view code (as you said when YES is clicked )

paste the code mentioned below

```
SecondViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vinay"];
        [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

let me know if any issues occur.

Answer (score 5):

May this helps:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ClassNameViewController *viewController = (ClassNameViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewIdentifierOnStoryboard"];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Have you set the identifier on your view and used the same storyboard name?

Comment: I've set the Storyboard ID to 'eerstekeer'. Checked the "Use Storyboard ID", import startup.h (classname) and used this code:

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
startup *viewController = (startup *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eerstekeer"];

Comment: There was one line that I forgot... the one to present the view. Without that, nothing really happens. Add the line and try again please.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is set the `UIAlertView` delegate to do this add `UIAlertViewDelegate` to your `@interface` so it looks like

```
      @interface myClass : super <UIAlertViewDelegate>
            // super could be anything like `UIViewController`, etc
      @end
```

and in the `@implementation` you can then added something like

```
      @implementation myClass

      ........... Some code


      - (IBAction)someActionMethod:(id)sender
      {
            UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                  message:@"Would you like to move on?"
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
             [myAlertView show];
             // [myAlertView release]; Only if you aren't using ARC
      }

      - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
      {
              switch(buttonIndex) {
                    case 1:
                          SecondViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
                          [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
         //  [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES]; // Deprecated in iOS 6.0
                          [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil]; // Introduced in iOS 5.0
                          break;
                    default:
                          break;
              }
      }

      @end
```

Remember to set the unique identifier in the storyboard. You can do this by going to your `.storyboard` and in the Identity Inspector (Selecting the third one in) you can set the `Storyboard ID` this is what you will need to match with what is in `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` so in the case above it would be `"secondViewController"`. It is that simple.

Remember to dismiss this view when you are done you will need to use

```
       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The above has actually been deprecated in iOS 6.0 but you can use

```
       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which does the same thing except it adds a completion block on the end.

Hope this helps.