# How to connect a UI alert button to another view Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have already created UI alert and call a function.

```
UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView
alloc]initWithTitle:@"Test"message:@"Working 1!!"delegate: self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView1 show];
```

Method for call newView viewController

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Cancel Tapped.");
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
   // NSLog(@"OK Tapped. Hello World!");
    UIViewController *newView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

I have created a new class named "newView" and also add "UIAlertViewDelegate" in present view controller.

But my problem is, I couldn't connect the newView viewcontroller with my present view controller.

Comment: are you using storyboard or xib

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: your coding is fine , you will need to optimize something

Comment: Kindly elaborate your question in detail. I think this is not enough about what you want to ask.

Comment: when I run this app and press the "Confirm" button, an empty black page showed up in my simulator.  where I want to show the **newView** controller page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Storyboard-view manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381418/open-storyboard-view-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating object in memory so that's why you can now only access properties and public methods of newView. Can not make presentation of newView.

You can achieve this by 2 ways.

Either you can make this possible by calling Segue or you have to create newView object from Storyboard.

```
ViewController *entryController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"go"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:entryController animated:YES];
```

Comment: how can I call a Segue ? can u plz explain @Chetan

Comment: segue is very easy process to achieve this

Comment: http://nscookbook.com/2012/12/ios-programming-recipe-3-creating-segues-with-the-storyboard-part-1/

Comment: you welcome @sahanoor. But Segue is best practice ever.